# Is there a command-line email client and auto-download attachment to a file?

Tags: command-line, email

Is there a linux email client that can run on command line and can be configured to fetch and automatically save attachments to the filesystem?

Im currently using Thunderbird and it has a nice add-on called 'Attachment extractor' which automatically downloads attachments to the filesystem once the mail arrives. My problem is I want to run a custom php script the can process the attached file once it arrives.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if you are receiving the email locally, metamail can probably do what you're looking for.  many linux distros have a package for metamail.

here's a little information about it: http://www.cs.umd.edu/faq/mime.html

Otherwise, you may be able to work something out with fetchmail + procmail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fetchmail](http://www.fetchmail.info/) and [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) to do this.  Procmail can be configured to execute a script that tests if an email has any mime encoded attachments (this could be as simple as just grepping the file for the MIME header) and then invokes [munpack](http://linux.die.net/man/1/munpack) if it has.

Procmail can execute pretty much anything you want, so you should be able to get it to run your php script or a shell wrapper.